# Conversion of PDF files to BMP and print

Tags: android, pdf, bmp

I need a working android code to print pdf files into bmp. The code which I had is able to print but the text is so blurry and shrinked that it is very difficult to read.The device used to print is small with a paper width of 384.
the printed text should be clear to read.

```
public class PdfToImage {

        private int ViewSize = 384;
        private String pdfErrorCode = null;
        private String pdfImageErrorCode = null;
        private String pdfImageSaveErrorCode = null;
        private String returnError = null;

        public String pdfToImage(File pdfFilePath) {
            PDFImage.sShowImages = true;
            PDFPaint.s_doAntiAlias = true;
            HardReference.sKeepCaches = true;
            try {
                RandomAccessFile pdfAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(pdfFilePath,
                        "r");
                byte[] pdfData = new byte[(int) pdfAccessFile.length()];
                pdfAccessFile.readFully(pdfData);
                returnError = pdfLoadImages(pdfData);

                pdfErrorCode = "SUCCESS";

            } catch (Exception ignored) {
                pdfErrorCode = "PDF FILE NOT FOUND"; 
            }

            if (returnError.equals("PDF TO BMP CONVERSION SUCCESS")) {
                return pdfErrorCode;   
            } else {
                return "FAILED";
            }
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        private String pdfLoadImages(final byte[] data) {

            try {
                ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.NEW(data);
                PDFFile pdfFile = new PDFFile(byteBuffer);
                PDFPage pdfPage = pdfFile.getPage(1, true);

                final float scaleImage = ViewSize / pdfPage.getWidth() * 0.95f;
                Bitmap bitmapPdfPage = pdfPage.getImage(
                        (int) (pdfPage.getWidth() * scaleImage),
                        (int) (pdfPage.getHeight() * scaleImage), null, true, true);
                SaveImage(bitmapPdfPage, 1);

                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmapPdfPage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                stream.reset();

                for (int i = 2; i <= pdfFile.getNumPages(); i++) {
                    pdfPage = pdfFile.getPage(i, true);
                    bitmapPdfPage = pdfPage.getImage(
                            (int) (pdfPage.getWidth() * scaleImage),
                            (int) (pdfPage.getHeight() * scaleImage), null, true,
                            true);
                    bitmapPdfPage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                    SaveImage(bitmapPdfPage, i);
                    pdfImageErrorCode = "PDF TO BMP CONVERSION SUCCESS";
                }
                stream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("error", e.toString());
                pdfImageErrorCode = "PDF TO BMP CONVERSION FAILED";
            }
            System.gc();
            return pdfImageErrorCode;
        }

        private String SaveImage(Bitmap pdfBitmap, int pageNumber) {

            String sdcardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .toString();
            File pdfDir = new File(sdcardPath + "/pdftobmp");
            pdfDir.mkdirs();

            String pdfToImageFileName = "pdf-" + pageNumber + ".png";
            File imageFile = new File(pdfDir, pdfToImageFileName);
            if (imageFile.exists())
                imageFile.delete();
            try {
                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                pdfBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, outputStream);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
                pdfImageSaveErrorCode = "IMAGE SAVED";

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                pdfImageSaveErrorCode = "IMAGE NOT SAVED";
            }
            return pdfImageSaveErrorCode;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is the source format? Letter/A4? Because then this just won't work this way because the PDF has already an exactly defined format and if you just shrink it, of course the text will be blurry. You would need a more dedicated way to extract text from the PDF and print it in a different format.

Comment: Actually I want to print it on a device with a paper width of 384 only.its a very small device.so is there any other way to get the pdf to print as BMP in a readable format?

Answer (score 0):

Here, you're compressing the image to 1/10 of the original quality:

```
bitmapPdfPage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 10, stream);
```

Why not try either removing the line, or adjusting the compression to a much higher value, say 90?

```
bitmapPdfPage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
```

**edit**

If that's not the case then I can give you some advice to debug it.

I'm wondering whether it's your loading or saving code that's causing the small, blurry sizes, so if I were you, I would place a debug breakpoint on the line that reads

```
SaveImage(bitmapPdfPage, i);
```

Then, in the list of variables, you'll be able to find `bitmapPdfPage` (in Android Studio), and view the bitmap itself. If the bitmap is small and blurry here, then maybe update the question with the knowledge that it's the loading code that is incorrect. If it's large and you can read the text then the converse is true and you know that it's the bitmap saving code that's at fault.

Comment: yeah.sorry for my mistake. It was 100 before. But i tried changing the code and forgot to change back. Suppose if it is 100, then how can i achieve printing with a perfect readable text.

Comment: @Krishna13 I've added some debug help, could you try it and update me with the results?

Comment: hi.yes i tried that and unable to get the correct output. same as before. the printed image is not readable except the heading.